# Flicker on Postback in Chrome Browser

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, telerik

In [this](http://212.26.1.198/cms/home.aspx) web application,there is a huge flicker on postback when accessed in Chrome browser. However, it does not happen in IE and Firefox.

What can be the possible cause?

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kukqvqh2us2p56g/Flickry_Navigation_in_Chrome.mp4?dl=0) is the video that shows flicker in Chrome and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hrcfwtm2hzuptlp/Smooth_Navigation_in_IE_and_Firefox.mp4?dl=0) is the video that shows smooth navigation in Firefox.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

ps: this web application uses Telerik controls.

Thanks

Comment: I see very few places that can postback. I called __doPostBack() in the console and I did not see any issues, the standard page disposal and reload happened in Chrome. Can you explain in more details what exactly is that flicked or add a video that shows the issue?

Comment: I have edited the post by providing the link to the videos you asked for.

Comment: Probably Chrome takes more time to draw something specific on your page (like a <body> with margin: auto or something like this. Try removing such rules or removing chunks from the master page layout to see what causes this. May be some element that takes time to resize (e.g., if you use things like window.onload to resize stuff with JS).

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

> switch off 'Hardware acceleration' from the Advanced Settings > System
>   options

This might solve your issue. This issue was raised as a bug in Chromium project earlier.

Also try to see the console if any errors are coming up.

I know that this is not a specific answer but hope this helps you.

Comment: It did not solve the problem. And I think that solution should be application specific. All the clients of this application who use chrome are complaining of this jerk/flicker.